# Removing Phase shift in ECG signal

Tags: fft, python, ecg, pca

I have ECG signal sampled at 100Hz & using Python to remove noise, and generate a template signal from the collection of ECG from a total of almost 4700 signals. I have removed the noise from ECG using PCA and now looking to 'stack' together signals on top of each other to generate a template signal which will serve as a filter to improve SNR. Now I have run into a little problem, some signals are shifted and I cannot manually go through 4700 signals to remove the shift, is there any method to remove the phase shift or align the signals.
The pictures depict the problem I am facing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try to cross correlate them to find the time shift

Comment: You could try detecting the QRS complex for example, and align them all based on the location? But you're going to have a hard time aligning signals that come from different heart rates...

Comment: As Jdip pointed out, aligning signal that come from different heart rates will be really difficult especially if there are multiple QRS complexes. Looking at your averages and templates I would not guess that these are ECG recordings.